# How to migrate Persistent Volumes within GKE clusters in the same project?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, persistent-storage

I have a GKE cluster running with several persistent disks for storage.
To set up a staging environment, I created a second cluster inside the same project.
Now I want to use the data from the persistent disks of the production cluster in the staging cluster.

I already created persistent disks for the staging cluster. What is the best approach to move over the production data to the disks of the staging cluster.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the open source tool [Velero](https://velero.io/) which is designed to migrate Kubernetes cluster resources.

Follow these steps to migrate a persistent disk within GKE clusters:

1. Create a GCS bucket:

```
BUCKET=<your_bucket_name>
gsutil mb gs://$BUCKET/
```

2. Create a [Google Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) and store the associated email in a variable for later use:

```
GSA_NAME=<your_service_account_name>
gcloud iam service-accounts create $GSA_NAME \
    --display-name "Velero service account" 

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL=$(gcloud iam service-accounts list \
  --filter="displayName:Velero service account" \
  --format 'value(email)')
```

3. Create a custom role for the Service Account:

```
PROJECT_ID=<your_project_id>
ROLE_PERMISSIONS=(
    compute.disks.get
    compute.disks.create
    compute.disks.createSnapshot
    compute.snapshots.get
    compute.snapshots.create
    compute.snapshots.useReadOnly
    compute.snapshots.delete
    compute.zones.get
    storage.objects.create
    storage.objects.delete
    storage.objects.get
    storage.objects.list
)

gcloud iam roles create velero.server \
    --project $PROJECT_ID \
    --title "Velero Server" \
    --permissions "$(IFS=","; echo "${ROLE_PERMISSIONS[*]}")"

gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $PROJECT_ID \
    --member serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL \
    --role projects/$PROJECT_ID/roles/velero.server

gsutil iam ch serviceAccount:$SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL:objectAdmin gs://${BUCKET}
```

4. Grant access to Velero:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create credentials-velero \
    --iam-account $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
```

5. Download and install Velero on the source cluster:

```
wget https://github.com/vmware-tanzu/velero/releases/download/v1.8.1/velero-v1.8.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf velero-v1.8.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz
sudo mv velero-v1.8.1-linux-amd64/velero /usr/local/bin/velero

velero install \
    --provider gcp \
    --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.4.0 \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --secret-file ./credentials-velero
```

Note: The download and installation was performed on a Linux system, which is the OS used by Cloud Shell. If you are managing your GCP resources via Cloud SDK, the release and installation process could vary.

6. Confirm that the velero pod is running:

```
$ kubectl get pods -n velero
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
velero-xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx   1/1     Running   0          11s
```

7. Create a backup for the PV,PVCs:

```
velero backup create <your_backup_name> --include-resources pvc,pv --selector app.kubernetes.io/<your_label_name>=<your_label_value>
```

8. Verify that your backup was successful with no errors or warnings:

```
$ velero backup describe <your_backup_name>  --details
Name:         your_backup_name
Namespace:    velero
Labels:       velero.io/storage-location=default
Annotations:  velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-gitversion=v1.21.6-gke.1503
              velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-major-version=1
              velero.io/source-cluster-k8s-minor-version=21

Phase:  Completed

Errors:    0
Warnings:  0
```

---

Now that the Persistent Volumes are backed up, you can proceed with the migration to the destination cluster following these steps:

1. Authenticate in the destination cluster

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <your_destination_cluster> --zone <your_zone> --project <your_project>
```

2. Install Velero using the same parameters as step 5 on the first part:

```
velero install \
    --provider gcp \
    --plugins velero/velero-plugin-for-gcp:v1.4.0 \
    --bucket $BUCKET \
    --secret-file ./credentials-velero
```

3. Confirm that the velero pod is running:

```
kubectl get pods -n velero
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
velero-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx   1/1     Running   0          19s
```

4. To avoid the backup data being overwritten, change the bucket to read-only mode:

```
kubectl patch backupstoragelocation default -n velero --type merge --patch '{"spec":{"accessMode":"ReadOnly"}}'
```

5. Confirm Velero is able to access the backup from bucket:

```
velero backup describe <your_backup_name> --details
```

6. Restore the backed up Volumes:

```
velero restore create --from-backup <your_backup_name>
```

7. Confirm that the persistent volumes have been restored on the destination cluster:

```
kubectl get pvc
NAME                                     STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
redis-data-my-release-redis-master-0     Bound    pvc-ae11172a-13fa-4ac4-95c5-d0a51349d914   8Gi        RWO            standard       79s
redis-data-my-release-redis-replicas-0   Bound    pvc-f2cc7e07-b234-415d-afb0-47dd7b9993e7   8Gi        RWO            standard       79s
redis-data-my-release-redis-replicas-1   Bound    pvc-ef9d116d-2b12-4168-be7f-e30b8d5ccc69   8Gi        RWO            standard       79s
redis-data-my-release-redis-replicas-2   Bound    pvc-65d7471a-7885-46b6-a377-0703e7b01484   8Gi        RWO            standard       79s
```

Check out this [tutorial](https://faun.pub/clone-migrate-data-between-kubernetes-clusters-with-velero-e298196ec3d8) as a reference.